# about the modification relation

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A stunted tree, or pool of stagnant water, roused into a sluggish
>   action **by the heavy rain of the preceding night**, skirted the path
>   occasionally; and, now and then, a miserable patch of garden-ground,
>   with a few old boards knocked together for a summer-house, and old
>   palings imperfectly mended with stakes pilfered from the neighbouring
>   hedges, bore testimony, at once to the poverty of the inhabitants, and
>   the little scruple they entertained in appropriating the property of
>   other people to their own use.

Does "by the
heavy rain of the preceding night" modify a tree or a pool or both?

source [THE BLACK VEIL](http://www.ibiblio.org/ebooks/Dickens/Dickens_Veil.pdf#search=%27The+Black+Veil+by+Charles+Dickens+full%27)

Comment: It seems to make more sense to me to say the water of the pool was roused by the heavy rain, because what would it mean for the tree to be roused?  Although it's hard to understand how a pool of stagnant water could be roused and still be stagnant...personally, this kind of writing is why I can't stand Dickens; he was paid by the word, and it shows.

Answer (score 1):

Neither, it modifies *roused*!  The pool was roused by the rain.  The long phrase is functioning as an adverb.

In his comment, @BillJ adds some vital information: the propositional phrase “by the rain” functions as an *adjunct adverbial*, which is

> [a word, phrase, or clause](https://parentingpatch.com/adjunct-adverbial-english-grammar/) that modifies an entire clause by providing additional information about time, place, manner, condition, purpose, reason, result, and concession.

In this case, the phrase supplied information on *cause*, which was for some reason omitted from the list.

Is the thing modified “roused” — or is it “the pool was roused”?  You make the call!

Comment: It would be better to say that the 'long phrase' is a preposition phrase functioning as an adjunct.